# how to incrementally flush memcached nodes to avoid downtime

Tags: memcached, flush, distributed-caching, spymemcached

I have a cluster of memcached nodes.  Flushing the cache currently wipes all of the nodes and then a service I have running is temporarily unavailable as it re-caches.

Does anyone know how I can flush one cache, then reload it with new cache data, then flush the next node and reload it's data, and so on?

Thanks!

Comment: just curious, what s your reason of doing that? why dont you come up with a good cache eviction policy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the value I want stored temporarily. When it is finished populating, I delete the old cache and swap.